# ionic ng-submit/ng-click/on-tap working on browser but not on android after building apk

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click

So i got this example found at: http://odhyan.com/blog/2014/12/building-a-simple-quiz-app-using-angularjs/
 , it's made as a desktop app, i copied the service, directive, controller in my ionic-app sources.

When i "ionic serve" and test the app in the browser, the application works as it should.

I managed to build the apk, but when i install it on native android (my phone Galaxy S6 Edge) and also tried in Android Studio (emulator - Nexus 5X used for tests in this case), the **submit button won't work**... I tried changing the "ng-click" to "ng-submit", "on-tap", "on-touch" one by one, and still not working.. i isolated the "ng-show"-s so i can try the other buttons. All are working properly (start quiz, next-question, Play again), but not the submit one.

What should i do to get this button working on android too as it works in desktop? Can anyone help please?

No errors in console while testing in browser where everything works as it should.
No errors at building app or ionic serving...

P.S. i tried all of the "answers found on stack overflow related to this behaviour" but no result :( !

Thank you very much !

Comment: Try using [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) to check what is actually going on when it runs on the device, and add any relevant errors to your post

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tip! I also tried this before posting this question, my problem is: i saw there only debugging web-pages on mobile with chrome, my problem is inside an application that i install on device.
I searched for tools like app-debugging for android, but with relevant results :(

Comment: Connect your developer enabled android device to your PC (via USB) and run `ionic run android --device`, then visit chrome://inspect/#devices - is that what you did?

Comment: Some example will help, please post your HTML markup and you JS controller code

Comment: @fadifannoun the whole mark-up and javascript is in the link above.